# How do I define custom shortcuts in WinEdt 10.2?

Tags: winedt

How do I define custom shortcuts like F7 for compiling with XeLaTex and F8 with LuaLaTex ? It's on MainMenu.ini and maybe how do I change F9 for LuaLaTex or XeLaTex if F7, F8 are taken..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Open the option interface (menu Options -> Options interface).

Double click on `Main Menu` in `Menus and Toolbars`

[image]

This will open your local `mainmenu.ini`.

## Search for the lualatex entry.

Select the value for the shortcut (or add one if you don't have one):

[image]

## Get the code for the shortcut

In the top bar of the option interface there will now be a small keyboard.
Use it to select a shortkey which will be copied to the ini-file.

[image]

## Load the changed ini-file

This is done with the leftmost symbol in the top bar of the option interface.

If the shortcut doesn't work this normally means that some other tool is already using the shortcut.

Comment: I have voted all your answers. Excellent.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+Alt+P (no other occurrences according to search) but still nothing..

Comment: Did you load the script?

Comment: Added SHORTCUT=:"49228::Ctrl+Alt+L" after MACRO. Saved, loaded the script, restarted for good measure. Clicked on a tex file, used the shortcut. I'm missing something..

Comment: I hope you don't have the colon after the equal sign. What did you do to load the script? Restarting doesn't do anything.  But you can rebuild all scripts also through options->maintenance->rebuild all.

Comment: Yes I did have the colon after the equal sign (copied the line below). It works, many thanks..

Answer (score 4):

The simplest is to use the short cut (`F9`) for a general `Compile` accessory: define the default compiler via the Tool Bar, as on this image:

[image]

and use the `F9` key.

This being said, you nevertheless may want to define your own shorts. Open the `Options Interface`, open `MainMenu.ini`, select an `ITEM`, and add under this item a line `SHORTCUT=" "` if it doesn't exist, then click on the `Insert Shortcut` button of the Options Interface (4th button from the left) and type the shortcut you want to set in the Popup window:

[image]

Last, click on the `Load Current Script` button (leftmost in the Options Interface).

Be aware that many shortcut keys are already used in the default settings. You can have list in WinEdt help. To see them, you have  `Default Shortcuts Overview`:

[image]

Comment: Bernard thanks, the answer was very similar to Ulrike's.

Comment: Great minds think together! ;-)

Comment: I clicked drop down menu in toolbar and selected LuaLaTeX but then also F9 compiles to PdfLaTeX only. Earlier I had been doing this and it used to compile to the selected compiler (LuaLaTeX) with F9. But I had to reinstall the whole system and then after it is not working. (Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit)